# $\operatorname{Spec}(A[\frac{b}{a}]) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion when $A$ is a Dedekind domain.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $a, b \in A$ with $a \neq 0$. I wonder if there is an elegant proof (using properties of Dedekind domain, not Zariski's main theorem of course) to show that $\operatorname{Spec}(A[\frac{b}{a}]) \longrightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion.

### Background:

This is (affine case of) exercise 4.1.14 in Liu Qing's book Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic curves.

EGA 4(3), Corollary 8.12.10

> Soient Y un préschéma intègre et normal, X un préschéma intègre, $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ un morphisme birationnel et localement quasi-fini (Errm , 20). Alors $f$ est un isomorphisme local ; pour que $f$ soit une immersion ouverte, il faut et il suffit que $f$ soit en outre séparé.

provides a general proposition which is itself a simple corollary of Zariski's main theorem.

The purpose of this exercise is (I guess) to examine the dimension one (Dedekind domain) case ''by hands''.

Comment: For a Dedekind domain $\operatorname{Spec}(A[\frac{b}{a}])= \operatorname{Spec}(A)-V$ where $V= \{ P\in Spec(A), v_P(a)> v_P(b)\}$ is a finite set of primes thus it is closed, for the separated stuffs $\Delta(X\times_Y X) = Spec(A[\frac{b}{a}]\otimes_A A[\frac{b}{a}] / (1\otimes \frac{b}{a}-\frac{b}{a}\otimes 1))$

Comment: Is it not always true, that $D(f) = \operatorname{Spec}(A[f]) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is an open immersion, for arbitrary rings $A$, and $f\in A$?